# Display MySQL queries on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms, html.dropdownlistfor

I've been searching for a while but nothing I've found match what I need.

I've got a form with `2 variables (dropdownlist) to query a DB (PHP and SQL)`.

Names of my variables are : `"province"` and `"candidat"`.

My result page is action.php with all the `sql/php` code for the results.

Everything is going very fine `except that after clicking on the submit button`, a new page is opening : `action.php` with the results of my request.

Now, I wish to display this results on the same page as `my form (id = form)`. The id of the div to display results is`"success" (<div id="success">)`. There is an action on my form : `action="action.php"`, should I remove it ?

I know that I have to use `AJAX method` but nothing that I've found match my needs. The other point is that I wish to be able to make another query and display the new results in this area.

If you know the solution or a tutorial that fit my needs... MANY THANKS of your help !

Answer (score 0):

**Start here:** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And do something along the lines of this:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    cache: false
  }).done(function( response ) {
    alert( response );
    $("#success").html(response); //put the response into a DIV with id="success"
  });
```

I'd recommend being more specific with your HTML id's that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var datastring = "your data that is pass for php file";
$.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    data: datastring,
    type: "post",
    success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
             }
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much : it works great ! Any idea to avoid a reloading page ?

Comment: something is wrong then because the page is always reloading, I will try again (and also not to become mad with this issue !) Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code :
        
                 PROVINCE
                 
                ">

```
            <?php
            }

            ?>

            </select>
```

CANDIDAT

```
            <?php

            $result = mysql_query($query);

            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            { 
            ?>
            <option  value="<?php echo $data['id_candidat']; ?>">
            <?php echo $data['pren1']; ?> <?php echo $data['nom_candidat'];  ?></option>

            <?php
                    $id = $data['id_candidat'];
                    if ($id === $id)
                    {break;}        
            }

            ?>
            </select>

            <br/>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="ok" />

            </form>
```

Content of action.php :